# How to create custom Toolbar in android ..?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I need  a custom toolbar for my app, can anyone help me to create toolbar like the image below

[image: Toolbar Image]

Back Button  in Left Title in Center  and  a Save Menu in Right.

Comment: this kind of questions are already available please before asking search properly, from next time please find first if you won't get help from existing question and answer then you can put your problem.

Comment: im searching from last two hours but nothing found yet

Answer (score 1):

**Use following xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="save"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```